# React native show statusbar instead of fullscreen

Tags: react-native

What can I change to open my React-Native App in Android in non-fullscreen mode? When I create an app, it forces it to be fullscreen.

This is what is rendered:

```
<SafeAreaView>
    <StatusBar
      barStyle="dark-content"
      hidden={false}
      networkActivityIndicatorVisible={true}
    />
```

I don't see the Status bar on top.

What I want is that the notifications can still popup from top. Now my App is forced in the full screen mode and foreground for some reason I can't figure out.

Is this something to configure via the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: use `View` instead of `SafeAreaView` with proper `flex`.

Comment: Hi fyi `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` is only on iOS

Comment: I recently faced this issue and I fixed it, I am sure some problem inside your code, I can take a look if you can share some reproducible code.

Comment: Can you try with this and let us know. <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#6a51ae" />

Answer (score 0):

1. `SafeAreaView` can be used inside regular view.

```js
<View>
    <StatusBar
      barStyle="dark-content"
      hidden={false}
      networkActivityIndicatorVisible={true}
    />
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
  //....
  </SafeAreaView>
</View>
```

2. Always use `flex:1` in `SafeAreaView`'s style.

```js
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
```

3. If there are multiple `StatusBar` components. It will use the last.
4. Try adding `backgroundColor="#fff"` to `StatusBar`